# What is default fonts in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, fonts, default

I was playing with my xubuntu (i.e. trying i3, other WM's, changing styles, etc.), but after all I understood that I can't recreate original system fonts. I tried many variations of DejaVu Sans, but it's all look pretty bad. Can you please tell me, what is default font in xfce4-terminal, and in xubuntu 16.04 itself? I don't want to reinstall my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xubuntu 16.04 uses **Noto Sans** as the default font for it's User interface. In previous releases, It used to use **Droid Sans** though.

In Ubuntu flavors, typically x`ubuntu-default-settings` package controls the default look and feel for a flavor. It's `xubuntu-default-settings` for Xubuntu, `lubuntu-default-settings` for Lubuntu.

The dependencies of `xubuntu-default-settings` verifies this -

```
xubuntu-default-settings
 |Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: <gsettings-backend>
    dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: xubuntu-artwork
  Depends: fonts-noto-hinted
  Depends: x11-common
  Depends: lightdm-gtk-greeter
  Recommends: xfce4-session
  Recommends: libxfce4ui-utils
```